# Why do I get “baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it” when baking with baking type combine? What does it mean?

Tags: texture-baking, baking, error

Why do I get a message saying

> Baking map saved to internal image, save it externally or pack it

when baking with baking type *Combine*?

What does *Internal Image*, *Save Externally* and *Pack* mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means that the bake worked, now you need to save the image that the bake has created, open the *Image Editor* or *UV Editor* and either pack it into the blend file itself or save it in a folder:

[image]